# array_combine stuck when there is no value in first array

Tags: php, arrays

i m using `array_combine()` but it display error when in first array there is no value.
how to get rid of this

**EDIT:**

```
First array  
Distance_Array
Array
(
    [0] => 
)

School_ID_Array
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
 and i m using
$Coverage_ Array=array_combine($School_ID_Array,$Distance_Array);   

which results

Coverage_ Array
Array
(
    [] => 
)

i want that in first array, if any value is empty , 
then  Coverage_ Array key accept any default key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditions like this:

```
if (isset($some_var_or_array) && !empty($some_var_or_array)) {
    // some code which using $some_var_or_array value(s)
}
```

**UDATED**

Here the function ArrayCombine(), which get three parameters: two arrays and third - the default parameter. The default parameter value will be set to the empty or nulled first array values:

```
function ArrayCombine($array1, $array2, $default = 0)
{
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($value) || empty($value)) {
            $array1[$key] = $default;
        }
    }
    return array_combine($array1, $array2);
}
```

Here the example:

```
$Distance_Array = array(
    1 => '',
);

$School_ID_Array = array(
    3 => 4,
);

$Coverage_Array = ArrayCombine($Distance_Array, $School_ID_Array);

var_dump($Coverage_Array);

/*
    var_dump output:
    array(1) {
        [24]=>
            int(4)
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

> **Errors/Exceptions**
>
> Throws `E_WARNING` if keys and values
>   are either empty or the number of
>   elements does not match.

So you need to ensure there is something in the array or don't call `array_combine()`. For example:

```
if (count($keys) > 0 && count($values) > 0 && count($keys) == count($values)) {
  $combined = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```